# AddHandler .htaccess on GoDaddy stopped working today

Tags: php, .htaccess, addhandler

I have the following code in my GoDaddy .htaccess file:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .do
FCGIWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php .do
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .do
```

This means that whenever we go to a ".do" file in the web browser, it runs as PHP. All of a sudden, after three years of working with no problem, it has stopped working correctly! Now, if I go to a .do file, the browser just downloads the file.

I think that GoDaddy have done a server upgrade, but I can't work out how to solve the problem.

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1):

**GoDaddy** upgraded EasyApache (from version 3 to version 4) last night.

You should drop the `FcgidWrapper` and the `AddType` directives from your .htaccess, and modify `AddHandler` to:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-lsphp .do
```

Refresh browser cache after change.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue.  We were able to fix it by replacing the module name to the Apache V 2.4 standard.

In your case, you would need to do:

```
AddHandler fcgid-script .do
FcgidWrapper /usr/local/cpanel/cgi-sys/php .do
AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .do
```

We referred the official Apache documentation [here](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/en/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidwrapper).  There might be more choices for your context.